# SSRS doesn't refresh variable when using lookup function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Report variable with lookup function with first parameter as static value

**Variables!MyTarget**

```
=Lookup("MyTarget", Fields!PropertyType.Value, Fields!SettingValue.Value, "CompanyTargets")
```

Variable is used all over the report. When I make any change to report file and save it everything works first time, then I run report again or refresh it and my variable is empty. Reports and datasets are not cached (cache is disabled).

What I tried:

- Setting DeferVariableEvaluation to True
- Move static value into report parameter and then provide default value
- Set data source for data set to process queries in one transaction
- Setting ReadOnly flag on variable to False

On side note. Data source is SSAS with dynamic parameters provided by report